# In SQL, what does a comma separated list in front of FROM mean?

Tags: sql

Here is an example:

```
 SELECT id AS customer_id
 FROM
   my_table s,
   s.event,
   event.section;
```

What exactly are we selecting from? Is this some sort of implicit join?

Comment: It means the writer of the code does not know how to write proper SQL.  You can convert it mentally by replacing the commas with `cross join`s.

Comment: This looks like `sql++` or some flavor of it like asterixdb or partiql where it's querying against json and an implicit cross-join is just the way it's done. What system are you running this in?

Comment: @TheImpaler If you note though that dialect where alias `s` is defined, and then a second table is brought in as `s.event` and then a third `event.section` suggests that this query is being run against non-relational data (probably a JSON file). `sql++` allows SQL like this, and in fact an `ON` isn't used when using that dialect. Essentially everything is sort of cross-joined. Perhaps there is some RDBMS that allows nested table queries like this too though?

Comment: @JNevill I think you are right.

Comment: I can't find any documentation from traditional RDBMS's that support JSON that use this nested table syntax (snowflake, postgres, and Teradata all use bracket, json paths, or dot notation). I've only seen this dialect in sql++ and implementations of sql++ as mentioned above. OP, essentially this is querying semi-structured data (like JSON) wherein there is an object `my_table` that has nested in it an object `event` and in that an object `section`. Somewhere in that nested data is a column `id` that is being selected. There is no `ON` because the join is derived from the structure of the data.

Comment: @JNevill: I was thinking those might be nested tables in Oracle, but that would require `from my_tables s, table(s.event) ...` to access the rows from the nested table